# Java Opengl 3D rendering

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to create several 3D blocks with a 2D texture, but is not working because some sides of the cubes are transparent to others. 
Here is a part of code from the class where I define the blocks:

```
    public void Render(){

            try {
        this.texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/gold1.png")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    squareDisplayList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(squareDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);
    {

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        //trás
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x2, y1, z1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x2, y2, z1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x1, y2, z1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);

        //cima
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x2, y1, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x1, y1, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x2, y1, z1);

        //baixo
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x2, y2, z1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x2, y2, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x1, y2, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x1, y2, z1);

        //direito
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x2, y1, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x2, y2, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x2, y2, z1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x2, y1, z1);

        //esquerdo
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x1, y1, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x1, y2, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x1, y2, z1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);

        //frente
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x2, y1, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x2, y2, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x1, y2, z2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x1, y1, z2);
        glEnd();

    }
    glEndList();

}

 public void Draw(){

    glCallList(squareDisplayList);

}
```

And here is the class here I call the several blocks:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective((float) 30, 880f / 580f, 0.001f,100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    for(int ix = 0; ix < world_width; ix++){

        for(int iy = 0; iy < world_hight; iy++){    

            for(int iz = 0; iz < world_height; iz++){

                render[ix][iy][iz].Render();

            }

        }

    }   

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glTranslatef(xspeed, -jumpsd, zspeed);

        for(int ix = 0; ix < world_width; ix++){

            for(int iy = 0; iy < world_hight; iy++){    

                for(int iz = 0; iz < world_height; iz++){

                    render[ix][iy][iz].Draw();

                }

            }

        }

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(35);

    }
```

How can I solve the transparency problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following code in your initialisation block:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```